# How to use navteq information for turn restrictions in pgrouting?

Tags: pgrouting

I'm developing a pgrouting application using navteq information but I don't know  how to use the navteq information to add turn restriction in pgrouting. Even, I don't know where to find this kind of information in the navteq tables. I guess this data would be in condition/Driving Manoeuvres.

Also, I'm tried to figure out how to use the divider information to add some turn restrictions in pgrouting but I guess that must be another source of information in this tables (navteq) that can be more easy and useful for turn restrictions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a good guide:

**Importing from NavTeq NavStreets Format**

*"We will describe how to import NavStreets format to pgRouting format. This can be done automatically by the script on the source code."*

***WARNING** As NavStreets has a propietary way of generating its datasources, we have no way to certify it will cover all dataset cases. You should check the final data to be sure the import has been done right.*

https://github.com/Emergya/GoFleetLSServer/wiki/Importing-from-NavTeq-NavStreets-Format